# How to scroll the scrollbar to the center of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am following this post.

[Scroll to the center of viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529070/scroll-to-the-center-of-viewport)

I do like the answer but when I use it, I got an error in my console.

```
  $('body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - ($(window).height()-$(this).outerHeight(true)) / 2
  }, 5000);
```

The error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

I am not sure why `$(this).offset() is undefined`. Can anyone help me about it?

Thanks!

Comment: i m not getting any error for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mention what "this" stands for. In the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529070/scroll-to-the-center-of-viewport) you mention, they are using the 'img' tag. Use this instead:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('body').animate({ scrollTop: $('body').offset().top - ( $(window).height() - $(this).outerHeight(true) ) / 2  }, 500);
});
```

Also, you might want to change the 5000 at the end to a smaller number. Else it will take 5 seconds to scroll to the center of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `$(this)`, use `$('body').offset()` instead. Looks like `$(this)` is referring to the window object which has no offset property.

Comment: Interesting, how could that possibly be when the OP is using `$('body')` explicitly in the outer call?

Comment: I looked a bit into the jQuery source, and it appears that the animation is being run using setTimeout in the context of the window and not the selector, though I could be wrong, it's a pretty complex library to step through. This appears to be the case though.

Comment: I think I see, it's because the call to `$(this)` is not inside of a function, so this is the `window`. I was thinking when you pass a function to `$.on` and that within there, this is the current element